# How can I view the entire value of a property in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have an object with a property (string, in the form of XML) that is used a few times and leading to unexpected results later on, so I need to find where/how it is changing to do so.
I've tried hovering on the property and pinning it, but I only get the small box that shows ~2 lines of the string. But it is a fairly large string so I'd like to see all or most of it. Kind of like the text/xml visualizer, except I can't take any debugging action in the VS window with that box open.
 Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333380/how-do-i-run-until-this-variable-changes-when-debugging

Comment: I normally use the OzCode Trace function (http://o.oz-code.com/features#trace) to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hovering the variable, use the magnifier icon left to the value. It will open a window with the variable contents.

Alternatively, add the variable to your Locals/Watch window.

Comment: The Watch window is ideal for this, it'll highlight the variable when it changes.

Comment: The window from the magnifier leads me to the Text/XML visualizers. I have to close that window between taking steps in the debugger since keeping that window open doesn't let me interact in the main VS window.

Comment: The watch window is close, but still only shows me a couple lines. However, I will have to look at the highlighted variable feature, @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Alt + Q after selecting an expression in code or Locals window for viewing variables related to the last and current line.